# Different Tor identities for different processes

Tags: fork, tor

I have a program that's using Tor as a proxy.
Can I somehow make forks of my program, such that each instance has its own Tor identity?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "Tor identity"?  You can have each forked child have its own Tor connection (by having each child make a separate connection to the Tor proxy), or you can have them share a Tor connection (by making one connection to the Tor proxy prior to forking, and sharing that connection).  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'd like each forked child had its own Tor connection and different ip visible to outter world. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Yes, just have each child connect separately to the tor proxy.

Comment: So simple, and I don't even have to make magic with ports, privoxy and other stuff?